# Mixing other languages with R

Tags: r, unix

I use R for most of my statistical analysis. However, cleaning/processing data, especially when dealing with sizes of 1Gb+, is quite cumbersome. So I use common UNIX tools for that. But my question is, is it possible to, say, run them interactively in the middle of an R session? An example: Let's say `file1` is the output dataset from an R processes, with 100 rows. From this, for my next R process, I need a specific subset of columns 1 and 2, `file2`, which can be easily extracted through `cut` and `awk.` So the workflow is something like:

```
Some R process => file1
cut --fields=1,2 <file1 | awk something something >file2
Next R process using file2
```

Apologies in advance if this is a foolish question.

Comment: See `?system` for how to run shell commands from within R.

Comment: @Joshua: In my opinion posting this as an answer would be better practice. It would cause the display of [r] questions to have a non-zero answer and allow it to be accepted.

Comment: Maybe.  I always feel a little guilty posting a super-short answer or one that I haven't explained in detail, so I leave it as a comment and let someone else (or the OP) re-post with more details as an answer ...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this (adding other `read.table` arguments if needed):

```
# 1
DF <- read.table(pipe("cut -fields=1,2 < data.txt| awk something_else"))
```

or in pure R:

```
# 2
DF <- read.table("data.txt")[1:2]
```

or to not even read the unwanted fields assuming there are 4 fields:

```
# 3
DF <- read.table("data.txt", colClasses = c(NA, NA, "NULL", "NULL"))
```

The last line could be modified for the case where we know we want the first two fields but don't know how many other fields there are:

```
# 3a
n <- count.fields("data.txt")[1]
read.table("data.txt", header = TRUE, colClasses = c(NA, NA, rep("NULL", n-2)))
```

The sqldf package can be used.  In this example we assume a csv file, `data.csv` and that the desired fields are called `a` and `b` .  If its not a csv file then use appropriate arguments to `read.csv.sql` to specify other separator, etc. :

```
# 4
library(sqldf)
DF <- read.csv.sql("data.csv", sql = "select a, b from file")
```

Comment: Great answers, all. I wish I could check both Grothendieck's and Dirk's responses as accepted. Many thanks.

Answer (score 6):

I think you may be looking for [littler](http://dirk.eddelbuettel.com/code/littler.html) which integrates R into the Unix command-line pipelines.

Here is a simple example computing the file size distribution of of `/bin`:

```
edd@max:~/svn/littler/examples$ ls -l /bin/ | awk '{print $5}' | ./fsizes.r 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max.    NA's 
      4    5736   23580   61180   55820 1965000       1 

  The decimal point is 5 digit(s) to the right of the |

   0 | 00000000000000000000000000000000111111111111111111111111111122222222+36
   1 | 01111112233459
   2 | 3
   3 | 15
   4 | 
   5 | 
   6 | 
   7 | 
   8 | 
   9 | 5
  10 | 
  11 | 
  12 | 
  13 | 
  14 | 
  15 | 
  16 | 
  17 | 
  18 | 
  19 | 6

edd@max:~/svn/littler/examples$
```

and it takes for that is three lines:

```
edd@max:~/svn/littler/examples$ cat fsizes.r 
#!/usr/bin/r -i

fsizes <- as.integer(readLines())
print(summary(fsizes))
stem(fsizes)
```

Comment: I think `litter` is a different package.  :)  That one tends to clog the pipes.

Answer (score 3):

See `?system` for how to run shell commands from within R.

Answer (score 3):

Staying in the tradition of literate programming, using e.g. org-mode and org-babel will do the job perfectly:

You can combine several different programming languages in one script and execute then separate, in sequence, export the results or the code, ...

It is a little bit like sweave, only that the code blocks can by python, bash, R, sql, and numerous other. Check t out: [org-mode](http://orgmode.org/) and [bable](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/) and an example using different programming [languages](http://orgmode.org/worg/org-contrib/babel/examples/data-collection-analysis.html)

Apart from that, I think org-mode and babel is the perfect way of writing even pure R scripts.

Answer (score 1):

Preparing data before working with it in R is quite common, and I have a lot of scripts for Unix and Perl pre-processing, and have, at various times, maintained scripts/programs for MySQL, MongoDB, Hadoop, C, etc. for pre-processing.

However, you may get better mileage for portability if you do some kinds of pre-processing in R.  You might try asking new questions focused on some of these particulars.  For instance, to load large amounts of data into memory mapped files, I seem to evangelize `bigmemory`. Another example is found in the answers (especially JD Long's) [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1727772/quickly-reading-very-large-tables-as-dataframes-in-r).